# A Peculiar Sum Of Squares

Tags: summation, sums-of-squares, telescopic-series

I have been trying to solve a question that arose in my mind a couple of days ago.

What is the sum of:

> $1+4+9+16+25+\cdots +n^2$?

*It is the sum of squares of each numbers starting from $1$ to $n$.*

**Can there be any formula for this sum?**

Answer (score 2):

$$1^2+2^2+...+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$
We can get it by the following way.

$$(n+1)^3-1=\sum_{k=1}^n((k+1)^3-k^3)=\sum_{k=1}^n(3k^2+3k+1)=$$
$$=3\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+3\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n$$ and the rest is smooth.